# Bicycle tire size between 590-584

Tags: tire

We have a old bike with a small tire problem 26 590 is too loose and 26 584 is too tight so is there something in between?

Comment: [The most comprehensive list I know of](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#iso) doesn't have anything in between. My suspicion is that it's 584, but at the big end of tolerance, but do you have more info? Any markings on an old tyre? What do you get if you try to measure the bead seat diameter (I'd work back from the circumference)

Comment: How old is old?  Are we talking pre-1960 vintage?    Or potentially something esoteric, or French ?